# Unable to read the HTML contents from a URL in Android

Tags: java, android, url

I was trying to read the HTML contents from a url. I tried with many samples and code examples from many sites, but it didn't work for me. When I run the code it leaves the default text in textview. I even tried with edittext as well. I have even added permission in the manifest file.

One of the codes I used is here: I have added the complete code here. I tried with all the code below with no success.

```
 package com.adn;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class REEActivity extends Activity {
    private static BufferedReader reader = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    try {
        ed.append(getStringFromUrl("http://www.google.com"));
        //getInputStreamFromUrl("").close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url){
       InputStream contentStream = null;

       try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
         contentStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
       } catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
       System.out.println("Content stream is " + contentStream);
       return contentStream;
    }


public static String getStringFromUrl(String url) throws IOException{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStreamFromUrl(url)));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try{
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
    }    
    }catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   getInputStreamFromUrl(url).close();
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
    06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adn/com.adn.REEActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:79)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.adn.REEActivity.getStringFromUrl(REEActivity.java:49)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at com.adn.REEActivity.onCreate(REEActivity.java:28)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-20 21:25:18.022: E/AndroidRuntime(14095):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adn"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".REEActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone please help me with this. I am new to Android as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
```

with

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuilder();
```

and also close your InputStrem using close() method

try to use this code in your second method, hope this will solve the problem

```
public static String getStringFromUrl(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStreamFromUrl(url)));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try{
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
    }    
    }catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getInputStreamFromUrl(url).close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I tried your updated code and it works now, and this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks I have tried this code but still I have problem. I have given the complete code in my question.

Comment: i copied and paste your code and it works for me!! have you added the Internet Permission?

Comment: Yes I have added the Internet Permissions in xml file I have added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: what error you get? post your logcat i tried your updated code and it works fine see result in attached image

Comment: post your AndroidManifest too

Comment: I have posted Manifest file as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12836/discussion-between-k-anas-and-vinay-kumar-j-g)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
public String getUrlContents(String url){
    String content = "";
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(url);
    ResponseHandler<String> rHand = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        content = hc.execute(hGet,rHand);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks I have tried this code but still I have problem. I have given the complete code in my question.